# reorder output from knitr

Tags: r, knitr

I am trying to model several characteristics of a data set by using comparative bar charts to depict the difference between earnings, completion, and efficiency rates for about 50 individuals in 5 states. I have my various charts grouped by regions to allow for comparisons between similar groups. I have 3 different chunks of code, one for each rate, and was wondering if there was some way to have R print out all of the results for one area print out together rather than having 5 plots for earnings, 5 for completion, and 5 for efficiency. I would like to have all 3 for CA together, followed by all 3 for IL, etc. 
SO isn't allowing me to attach code and data because there is too much of it to display.

Comment: Perhaps you may want to have a look at the [`egg`](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/egg/vignettes/Overview.html) package.

Comment: Could you post your code example as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/) on github.com or a [snippet](https://gitlab.com/explore/snippets) on gitlab.com?